# Why is this QObject subclass created in a different thread than its parent?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qthread

I'm running into some Qt threading issues that I don't understand, running Qt5.6 on Windows 7. Everything is installed and built using MSYS2.

I've created a `Server` object, which manages a `Device` object on behalf of remote clients. Both are subclasses of `QObject`. After the `Server` receives a client request to create a device, the `Device` is constructed with the `Server` as its parent.

But when I run the application in GDB, calling `this->parent()` for the `Device` returns a `NULL` pointer, indicating that this object has no parent. Furthermore, `this->thread()` returns a different thread from the `Server` object's thread. And the requisite `"Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread"` warning is printed, somewhere in the `QObject` constructor itself.

This is despite the `Device` object's constructor being passed the `Server` as its parent and there being *no other explicitly-created threads*. There are no explicitly-created `QThread` objects, and I'm only using the default event loop created by `QCoreApplication::exec()`. Furthermore, compiling and running this on either Linux or OS X confirms that the parent is set correctly and that both objects live in the same thread.

I understand why a call like `setParent()` or its moral equivalent will fail, to keep objects and their corresponding event loops in the same thread. But it appears that the thread affinity for the `Device` object is somehow already set by the time the constructor is called. But why is there more than one thread in the first place? And why only on Windows? And why would the object be created in a seemingly random thread, when it could very well use the thread of the parent that I'm passing in the constructor?

EDIT:

A couple of other things to note. I am not only not calling `moveToThread()` or anything like that, but there's no concurrency of any kind. This includes things like `QRunnable` or anything from the `QtConcurrent` module.

Another thing that actually solves the practical problem, but that I don't understand, is that this goes away if I compile for release. I've been using the debug build during development, which is apparently the only time the strange thread/parent behavior manifests. When I run the release build, everything works swimmingly. Is it possible this is a bug in the MSYS2 build of GDB that I'm using? Maybe there's some way in which Qt is not playing nicely with GDB (or vice versa)?

EDIT 2:

Based on a comment from @Ben, I dug around in more depth in the `QObject` constructor code (found [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#_ZN7QObjectC1EPS_) which starts on line 821. On line 826, ultimately the function `QThreadData::current()` is called, and this is where the threads of the parent and child first seem to differ. The Qt internal class `QThreadData`'s static function `current()` (found [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp.html#_ZN11QThreadData7currentEb)) seems to query thread-local storage to return the current thread's index, I think, which appears different from that of the parent's thread. I don't know enough about the Windows threading libraries to know if this is really what's going on, but after reading the `pthread`-based version of the code, that's my best guess.

I'm pretty far down the rabbit hole at this point, but it seems like my amended question is: Why does `QThreadData::current()` return a different thread from the parent? Or why has the thread-local storage containing this data changed between the time the parent was constructed and the child's constructor is called?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume from the thoroughness of your question that you haven't used `moveToThread()` anywhere, but I have to ask anyway. In fact,  are you doing *any* concurrent work? `QtConcurrent`, `QRunnabble`?

Comment: @JonHarper Nope, no concurrency at all. See edits.

Comment: Stop it in the debugger, look at the thread list, look at the call stack of the rogue thread, and see what function the rogue thread started in. That should give you a clue.

Comment: @Ben There is no "rogue thread". All of the code I've written is in the same thread. There are a couple of other threads running, stopped in Windows IO completion port code (which I don't really know), but my guess is that these are managed by the QtNetwork module. Also, see my second edit for more details about where the thread discrepancy begins.